# How can I access language strings from a cucumber step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, cucumber

I'm trying to do this:

```
Then /^I should see a message saying I have no narratives$/ do
  page.should have_content t(:no_narratives_on_recent_activity_page)
end
```

but t() is not available. The idea is that if I enter the expected text manually, then alter the i18n string later it'll break the step, so I want to test using the i18n string in the first place.

How can I access the t() helper (or something equivalent) in the cucumber step?

Answer (score 0):

`I18n` should be loaded, so you can simply send methods directly (rather than using helpers)

```
Then /^I should see a message saying I have no narratives$/ do
  page.should have_content I18n.t(:no_narratives_on_recent_activity_page)
end
```